# Something went wrong saving the application. Try again

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Whenever I try to edit my apps scope, I get this error:

> Something went wrong saving the application. Try again.

Not really that helpful in my opinion. Can someone help me out on this? Thanks in advance.